# Mongo connect problem using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I wrote these lines in My Application start event:

```
    var mongo = new Mongo();
    mongo.Connect();
    var blog = mongo.GetDatabase("Blog");
    mongo.Disconnect();
```

but on this line: `mongo.Connect();` it gave me this error:

> No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:27017

I am a beginner using Mongodb and i am just try to make sample code to see it's power.
So i have no idea how to solve this problem.

I am using VS2008 with MongoDB.Driver on Windows7.

**UPDATE**

I got also that the same problem is happening while trying this tutorial: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial#Tutorial-GettingADatabaseConnection
using the shell.

Comment: yes, in the tutorial i wrote : use mydb and it worked, but 'Inserting Data into A Collection' gave me the error that it can't connect to 127.0.0.1:27017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem, the problem that mongodb is pointing to the default database directory  c:\data\db

now i will try to get how to change this directory to another one.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo

Comment: thanks, how did you find out? It is always helpful to know how to debug better.

Answer (score 1):

When this problem occurs, you must delete the mongod.lock file. MongoDB then immediately creates a new lock, and the service becomes available again.

BTW, in order to work with MongoDB more easily, check out MongoVUE at http://www.mongovue.com.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem what you can do is just check your `dbpath` in `mongod.cfg` file in your mongo folder.

It should be the exact path of your data folder like for example `dbpath=e:\data\db`.